# How to show tooltip on top of listview's items

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Is it possible to set location for tooltip to show it on top of items (without offset)?
Like it's done in TreeView in RegEdit and File Explorer.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do something like below and set ListView's ***ShowItemToolTips*** property to **true**.

```
ListViewItem listViewItem = new ListViewItem("add");

listViewItem.ToolTipText = "Your Text Here";
myListView.Items.Add(listViewItem);
```